# Set String and get its value after form unhide

Tags: vb.net

I am currently trying to make an address book application. It checks on load if there is default address book in application directory. If there is not then user can open selected address book. I have problem with setting selected file as current file. Anything works great until I open second form which adds new contact to file and add it. Contact adds to file selected in first form  but when I close this "add form" then current xml path resets and program asks for address book to open again instead of opening xml file which I modified in "add contact form". Even if I set xmlCurrentPath in "add contact form" it still clear after contacts form is shown again. This is my code:

```
Public Class Form2
Private myTable As New DataTable()
Dim path = My.Application.Info.DirectoryPath
Dim xmlDefaultPath As String = path + "\address.xml"
Dim xmlCurrentPath As String
Dim fileDlg As New OpenFileDialog
Public isXml As Boolean = False

'Sets current xml path
Public Sub setCurrentPath(ByVal path As String)
    xmlCurrentPath = path
End Sub

Public Sub XmlExistence(ByVal xmlpath As String)
'Checks if current xml path exists and if not then checks if there is a default address book file in root directory
    If IsNothing(xmlCurrentPath) Then
        If System.IO.File.Exists(xmlpath) Then
            xmlCurrentPath = xmlDefaultPath
        Else
            xmlCurrentPath = ""
        End If
    End If
End Sub

Public Sub LoadForm(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Me.Shown
'checks if there is current xml path and if not asks if you want to choose from file
    If IsNothing(xmlCurrentPath) Then
        XmlExistence(xmlDefaultPath)
        If Not xmlCurrentPath = "" Then
            CreateTable()
            LoadXml(xmlCurrentPath)
        Else
            CreateTable()
            Dim addressfile = MessageBox.Show("Brak pliku adresów w katalogu głównym programu. Czy chcesz wybrać plik z dysku ? Jeśli wybierzesz nie zostanie utworzony nowy plik.", "Pytanie", MessageBoxButtons.YesNo)
            If addressfile = Windows.Forms.DialogResult.Yes Then
                fileDlg.Title = "Otwórz plik adresów"
                fileDlg.Filter = "XML Files|*.xml"
                fileDlg.ShowDialog()
                xmlCurrentPath = fileDlg.FileName
                LoadXml(xmlCurrentPath)
            End If
        End If
    End If

End Sub
```

How can I make it so after new contact is added to previously selected address book, when add contact form closes, then address book form will show this address book again.